# Are there too many flavors competing in this side dish?

Tags: flavor

I am going to make maple roasted Brussels sprouts for a party tomorrow with toasted almonds and cranberries. However, I wanted to add a sauce for the side and I was thinking something garlic-y, probably an aioli type of dip with mustard.

Does that sound like too much going on between the maple, cranberry, garlic and mustard? I would normally experiment and just see for myself but I don't have time to go back to the supermarket between now and the party.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you really mean "dip"?

Comment: Yes? Kind of? I wanted to add something extra alongside and I figured that some type of dip could work.

Comment: Are the almonds and cranberries going to be so well stuck on the sprouts that you can actually dip them, though? Seems like you're going to end up either putting the sauce straight on, or sort of mixing them on the plate, not so much dipping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toasted almonds match well with hazelnuts, cumin, nutmeg, rosemary, vanilla and cinnamon.

Cranberries do match well with garlic, lime, chili and onion.

So from a flavor-pairing point of view, if you want a spicy dip, it would be better to make a cranberry dip in itself with cranberries, sugar, chili, pineapple and coriander, like a chutney.

Mustard is a gamble. Cranberries do match well with some acidity, like lime or pineapples. I would be worried about the vinegar to be too stingy.

If it's a garlic-based dip, I would focus on garlic, onions, rosemary and cumin.

Comment: @Mark Feel free to select my answer as "Best answer" next to the vote buttons. This also helps to indicate to other people that this question is resolved.